# WP not reading localization files

Tags: localization, wordpress

Hi I've got problem with translations in WP.

It looks like my WP is not reading translation files (.po/.mo).

I am using Roots theme which have from the beginnig support of localization

```
load_theme_textdomain('roots', get_template_directory() . '/lang');
```

However WP still output 'text' instead 'texttekst' in _e('text', 'roots')

I am also using a CodeStyling Localization which works quite well
And for changing locale Xili Language plugin.

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

did you try to change in the wp-config.php file . 
Just look for the line define('WPLANG', 'xx_XX'); ( line number 72 in my pack) and chagne xx_XX to your the language you expected. also don't forget to load the mo/po file. 
a good software you would use is poedit to translate the text.
good luck

Comment: well my standard procedure installing wp is to put pl_PL in those lines, after that wordpress detect that my lang is different and ask if I want to reinstall in my lang ;)
however thanks for reply ;)